# Can environment variables be set at run time (production) in a rails app?

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, web-scraping, environment-variables, production-environment

I have a web app i am building whose core functionality involves performing automated CRUD tasks on amazon. Given the correct user login and password, the app user will be able to delete and add addresses on amazon. I am using selenium web-driver with mozilla agent for the automation task. At the moment, the user-name and password are hard-coded in the application.yaml file using figaro gem. What i want is for anyone accessing the app to be able to enter their own amazon username and password so the address deletion and removal process happens on their own amazon account.

Is there a way i can capture the current users's login and password via a form (with their consent of course) and set these as environment variables at runtime in secrets.yaml. So the login name becomes

```
  amazon_user_name: <%= ENV["SECRET_USER_NAME"] %>
```

and the password becomes

amazon_pass_word: <%= ENV["SECRET_PASS_WORD"] %>

Or is there an overall better and neater way to get this done?

Just to further clarify and simplify: All i want to do is allow users a means of logging into their amazon account via my app so my app can perform the address automation (adding and deleting shipping addresses in bulk) on their amazon account. Any secure means of accomplishing this is welcome.

Comment: Would creating a table for saved usernames/passwords not work? This would allow you to encrypt those password while in the database.

Answer (score 1):

for a per user setup, the easiest thing would be to set it in the user session, encrypted if you like.

like this:

`session[:super_secret_pass] = 'somepassword'`

then pass it down from the controller to where you are invoking it.

Comment: Just a heads up... most rails security recommendations say not to save these secrets in sessions.

Comment: sure - you could put them in db with some salt on the user's model as a field, or something else.  just not as an environment variable, as that is an app wide and not user specific

Comment: Is he trying to use the info outside of the rails environment?

Comment: The info is only needed to log into amazon